# Specify return type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I wanna narrow down type when returning data from function smartly (hopefully without using if statement etc)

I have the following code

```js
enum TypeData {
  Data1 = 'data1',
  Data2 = 'data2',
  Data3 = 'data3',
}

type DataType = {
  [TypeData.Data1]: {d1: number};
  [TypeData.Data2]: {d2: string};
  [TypeData.Data3]: {d3: number};
}

type Child = DataType[TypeData]

const dataType: DataType  = {
  [TypeData.Data1]: {d1: 1},
  [TypeData.Data2]: {d2: 2},
  [TypeData.Data3]: {d3: 3},
}

const getChild = (typeData: TypeData): Child => {
  return dataType[typeData]
}

const data = getChild(TypeData.Data2)
```

In the code, the function returns `Child` type, but `Child` type represents like

```js
type Child = {
    d3: number;
} | {
    d1: string;
} | {
    d2: number;
}
```

instead of specific data type like `{ d3: number }`. How to make it possible to specify the return data type instead of union of all types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of TypeScript Generics in order to return the correct type depending on the given input. Like so:

```
enum TypeData {
  Data1 = 'data1',
  Data2 = 'data2',
  Data3 = 'data3',
}

type DataType = {
  [TypeData.Data1]: {d1: number};
  [TypeData.Data2]: {d2: number};
  [TypeData.Data3]: {d3: number};
}

const dataType: DataType  = {
  [TypeData.Data1]: {d1: 1},
  [TypeData.Data2]: {d2: 2},
  [TypeData.Data3]: {d3: 3},
}

const getChild = <T extends TypeData>(typeData: T): DataType[T] => {
  return dataType[typeData]
}

const data = getChild(TypeData.Data2)
```

See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2AEQIYBdVQN4CgpRqYCMUAvFAOQAmGqxlANPoXQEzlW2ZtMtGoAzJxp1BfAL65c6RMFaZ4STngIBtJSjoA6AcQC6ALhzVix8BABGwAE4SA3Cw1yBu9kZNtzka3cfrNVwFBD2xqQW8rWwdcKVwAYwB7EABndChuVE1jAU0CClUoZyQgugNjMLMoYglmAJcdATZQ6i8oNlqnQMaxFoioQU64pNT0gHNgdABhAAsASwAbak4AHhgoYAAPdFBqFNgGzAA+AApZErpjGABKHLpNDX1yI5wWG0mwGxAM+7k1c60mH0sWkIzSP0wnAm03mSxO3Uwbh411wQA)